# How to make objdump -D only display specific function in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, objdump

I want to display the machine code of a specific function. For example, in Linux I would enter:

```
objdump -D x.out | grep -A20 main.:
```

What would the equivalent be in Windows?

Comment: OS agnostic question that actually asks how to make it dump just one function, not just a `grep -A`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769246/disassemble-one-function-using-objdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would the equivalent be in windows?

Off the top of head, you just save the output into a file:

```
objdump -D x.out > x.out.dump
```

then open the file (`x.out.dump`) in the text editor of choice.

On Windows to peek into the object code I find myself mostly using GUI debuggers. Windows is not very command-line friendly environment. Otherwise, you might want to install the [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/), start bash in terminal or the cmd.exe and use the grep as if you were under Linux.