# The cause of incorrect for loop entry

Tags: c++, multithreading, gnu, c++03

I have a simple for loop (though it is not the only component within the method) that is compiled with GNU 4.8.1.10 compiler with debugging option is off and optimization levels O-0, O-2 and O-3 distinctively. The loop is as below:

```
const int iMyConst = 10; // defined in another header
void myFunc(uint8_t ui8InputNum)
{
  // some stuff 
  for(int i=static_cast<int>(ui8InputNum); i<iMyConst; i++)
  { // loop content
   }
}
```

What happens is that, when I call `myFunc(10)` (equal to `iMyConst`), the for loop is executed. This is not the expected behaviour. Inside the loop I printed the variable values as well. They are printed as expected but with an exception: `i<iMyConst` came out to be `true` where `i` was printed as `10`. Moreover, I forced all process to run on single core, the unexpected behaviour happened again.

I ran the code in debug mode, and saw that the loop is not executed as expected. Then I defined the loop variable as `volatile int i`, this time the loop is not executed as well.

The problem might sound odd but it is all what happened. What is the cause of this problem? The system is 64-bit and has 12 cores.

```
// main.cpp
//============================================================================
// Name        : loopProblem.cpp
//============================================================================
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    a* myA = new a;
    b* myB = new b;
    myB->itsA = myA;
    myB->dummyFunc();
    delete myA;
    delete myB;
    return 0;
}
```

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include <stdint.h>
// #include <cstdint> not available in c++03

class a
{
    public:
        a();
        ~a();

        void myFunc(uint8_t ui8InputNum);
};



#endif /* A_H_ */
```

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "c.h"
#include <cstdio>

a::a()
{
}

a::~a()
{
}

void a::myFunc(uint8_t ui8InputNum)
{
    // some stuff

    for(int i=static_cast<int>(ui8InputNum); i<iMyConst; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d, comp: %d\n", i, (i<iMyConst));
    }
}
```

```
// b.h
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

class a;

class b {
public:
    b();
    ~b();
    a* itsA;

    void dummyFunc();
};

#endif /* B_H_ */
```

```
// b.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
#include <cstddef>

b::b() : itsA(NULL)
{
}

b::~b()
{
}

void b::dummyFunc() {
    itsA->myFunc(10);
}
```

```
// c.h
#ifndef C_H_
#define C_H_

const int iMyConst = 10;

#endif /* C_H_ */
```

Comment: The nastier the bizarre behaviour, the more likely a [mre] is a must to get to the bottom of the problem. For all we know there's a race condition that exposes a bit of UB that just happens to alter the value of `i`. The missing return type on `myFunc` probably doesn't help, though.

Comment: Shall we assume the function is declared properly with a specified return type? Submit a proper [mcve]. And don't be surprised if you discover the issue yourself whilst building it. The fact that you mentioned several times the core-count and SMP nature of the runtime conditions suggests there's a helluvalot more going on here than you're hinting at. The function as-shown has no reentrancy issues, but for all we know you're grasping and SMP has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: This sort of thing is often what happens when you have some form of "undefined behaviour" and the optimizer makes assumptions that aren't true. In this case, it seems like the optimizer thinks the loop always runs at least once. Can you show us the assembly code for your loop?

Comment: @user4581301 @WhozCraig , I checked it several times, the return type and declaration should be fine and it is `void` indeed. I will try to generate an example set of files.

Comment: @user253751 , I didn't check the assembly code, but I can go through that in debug mode with instruction stepping I suppose?

Comment: "Inside the loop I printed the variable values as well" let us see that code. Currently we are looking at code that is different from yours and probably has completely different behavior. Consider that you don't know where the problem really is, so leaving out seemingly unrelated stuff might be just where the actual problem is. [mcve] please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769246/how-to-disassemble-one-single-function-using-objdump

Comment: I added the example code, if anyone interested. @idclev463035818

Comment: [Can't preproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/noK3en) - what if you print `iMyConst` in the function? Does it print `10`?

Comment: @tedLyngmo yes it printed correctly 10.

Comment: @ErdemTuna Odd. I used the same compiler version and options. Can you try to declare `extern const int iMyConst;` in `c.h` and move the definition of 
`iMyConst` into `c.cpp`? It's just a shot in the dark, but worth trying. It shouldn't be a problem in this case, but ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried that as well, didnt work...

Comment: Can out of bounds read/write of an array at an earlier point in the code cause such a problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a fresh installation of the toolkit?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't try to reinstall the toolkit, but I will try that, thank you for the suggestion. If it fails either, then it is related with runtime behaviour...

Comment: I see that I missed a part of the question: "_Can out of bounds read/write of an array at an earlier point in the code cause such a problem?_" - Yes, it can. In fact, that could gravitate a black hole close enough to swollow the entire multiverse. The C++ specification does not exclude that scenario. If your code contains more than you've shown - it may have been subjected to such a scenario. (undefined behavior)

Comment: I didn't realize such a thing until the very last minute, something popped in my mind. I might have missed that, I will check it and update the situation @TedLyngmo.

Comment: @TedLyngmo there is an out of bound read in myFunc before the if check.

Comment: @ErdemTuna Ok. Do you still have the same problem after having fixed that bug?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The behaviour is now as expected after fixing the bug. Thank you for your help.