# Parse `objdump -dj .text <binary>` result

Tags: assembly, disassembly, objdump

I have a collection of binaries in the format of ELF. I am trying to retrieve the source code and compare it with the assembly so that I could have better understanding about the compiling process.

Now I could de-assemble the ELF based on the great solution [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/objdump-how-to-output-text-eg-ascii-strings-alongside-assembly-code/14639), which uses the following command

```
objdump -dj .text <binary>
```

and outputs something that looks like

```
00000000004035ed <version_etc>:
  4035ed:   48 81 ec d8 00 00 00    sub    $0xd8,%rsp
  4035f4:   4c 89 44 24 40          mov    %r8,0x40(%rsp)
  4035f9:   4c 89 4c 24 48          mov    %r9,0x48(%rsp)
  4035fe:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  403600:   74 37                   je     403639 <version_etc+0x4c>
  403602:   0f 29 44 24 50          movaps %xmm0,0x50(%rsp)
  403607:   0f 29 4c 24 60          movaps %xmm1,0x60(%rsp)
  40360c:   0f 29 54 24 70          movaps %xmm2,0x70(%rsp)
  403611:   0f 29 9c 24 80 00 00    movaps %xmm3,0x80(%rsp)
...
```

So I will try to retrieve `version_etc.c` file in the source tree and compare it with this assembly snippet.

I know there are some correspondence between the first two columns and the last two columns. However, I am not quite interested in those first two columns.

I am wondering if there is any tool that could help me extract the **last two** columns as a string and pair it with the header (in the example, `version_etc`).

I know I could simply write a script that uses regular expressions or similar to do this, but that would be error-prone (corner cases, etc.), it would be great if I could use some more principled way to do this extraction.

Comment: Are you hoping to get asm source you could re-assemble?  Use Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler (http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) which directly does that in the first place, including using labels for branch targets.  [How to disassemble, modify and then reassemble a Linux executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/58356507)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the reply! Actually I am trying to retrieve the source code (in the example, the source should be named `version_etc.c`) and compare it with the assembly so that I could have better understanding about the compiling process. So ideally, I would have a Python dict that looks like `filename: (source, binary)` (I will add this to the problem description).

Comment: Oh, if you do already have the source, you can just get the compiler asm output directly without going through binary, so you still have labels and whatnot: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  Especially https://godbolt.org/ is nice for matching up source with asm.

Comment: Other options: for a binary with debug info, objdump or GDB can do that for you.  [How to disassemble one single function using objdump?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22775364) / [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1289881) , or have the compiler output mixed asm and source without actually compiling to binary - [How can I see the assembly code for a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840321)